# How to Unit Test Delete operation using moq and xUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to Unit Test CRUD operations for an API in my WEB API project. I have a hard time figuring out how to do that for DELETE. Below is my service;

```
public async Task DeleteCompany(int id)
{
    var query = "DELETE FROM Companies WHERE Id = @Id";
    using(var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, new {id});
    }
}
```

Here's the controller

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCompany(int id)
{
    var company = await _companyRepository.GetCompanyById(id);
    if (company == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    await _companyRepository.DeleteCompany(id);
    return NoContent();
}
```

And below is the code for Unit Testing

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
public async Task CompanyController_DeleteCompany_ShouldReturnStatusCode204(int id)
{
    var mockCompany = new Mock<ICompanyRepository>();
    mockCompany.Setup(service => service.DeleteCompany(id))
           .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
           .Verifiable();

    var sut = new CompanyController(mockCompany.Object);

    var result = (OkObjectResult) await sut.DeleteCompany(id);

    result.StatusCode.Should().Be(204);
}
```

It turned out that it returns a null value of my model (Company in this example) after debugging. That's why the test doesn't pass and it gets to `NotFound` error in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html)'s `GetCompanyById` method so that it doesn't return null:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
public async Task CompanyController_DeleteCompany_ShouldReturnStatusCode204(int id)
{
    var mockCompany = new Mock<ICompanyRepository>();
    mockCompany.Setup(service => service.GetCompanyById(id))
        .ReturnsAsync(/*pass non-null value here*/);
    var sut = new CompanyController(mockCompany.Object);

    var result = (OkObjectResult) await sut.DeleteCompany(id);

    result.StatusCode.Should().Be(204);
    mockCompany.Verify(service => service.DeleteCompany(id);
}
```

On the other hand, you don't need to set up `DeleteCompany` as a verifiable action since it doesn't return anything anyway. [Mocks for Commands, Stubs for Queries](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/23/mocks-for-commands-stubs-for-queries). Use `mockCompany.Verify` instead, as shown above.